# How do we convert uint8[3] to uint8[]?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, solc

So the code is

```
struct A {
    uint8[] a;
}
```

I want to initialize `A` by `A a = A([1,2,3]);`. However, solc says that can't convert `uint8[3]` to `uint8[]`.

In conclusion, I am looking for a way to convert fixed-length array to dynamic-sized array. (without recreating the array by `push` n times)

Answer (score 2):

This works:

```
contract Test {
    struct A {
        uint8[] a;
    }
    A one;
    A[] many;

    function Test() {
        one.a = [1, 2, 3];

        many.length++;
        many[0].a = [1, 2, 3];
    }
}
```

---

As a side note, to show you the storage layout of an array, if you have this contract:

```
contract Test1 {
    uint8[3] a; // Fixed size
    function Test1() {
        a = [1, 2, 3];
    }
}
```

Then after deployment, you get the following:

```
> web3.eth.getStorageAt(test1Address, 0) // Slot 0
"0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000030201"
                                                             ^^^^^^ 3 values here
```

See how the 3 values are packed right on slot 0.

On the other hand, if you have this contract:

```
contract Test2 {
    uint8[] a; // Dynamic size
    function Test2() {
        a = [1, 2, 3];
    }
}
```

Then after deployment, you get the following:

```
> web3.eth.getStorageAt(test2Address, 0)
"0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003"
// That's the length of the array on slot 0
> var arrayLocation = web3.sha3("0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000", { encoding: "hex" })
// That's 0x290decd9548b62a8d60345a988386fc84ba6bc95484008f6362f93160ef3e563 BTW
> web3.eth.getStorageAt(test2Address, arrayLocation)
"0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000030201"
```

See how the 3 values are sent to a pseudo-random location.

More in [Layout of State Variables in Storage](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/miscellaneous.html#layout-of-state-variables-in-storage)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure where string came up. When I tried it, it complained about int8[] to uint256[] so I fudged the struct to match uint8[]. Also notice that I defined the array length as 3 so we aren't trying to force a fixed length array into a dynamic length array.

```
contract test {

    struct A {
      uint8[3] a;
    }

    A a = A([1,2,3]); 

    function getb() returns(uint8[3] whatWeGot) {
        return a.a;
    }
}
```

Looking again at your headline question. If the goal is a dynamic length array that starts with three values, then I would initialize with push(). Maybe something like this:

```
contract Test {

    struct Struct {
      uint[] myArray;
    }

    Struct myStruct; 

    function Test()  {
        myStruct.myArray.push(1);
        myStruct.myArray.push(2);
        myStruct.myArray.push(3);
    }

    function getter(uint index) returns(uint value) {
        return myStruct.myArray[index];
    }

}
```

Because you mentioned "string", there are some important differences between bytes and strings for this sort of thing.

Hope it helps.

Comment: oops. thanks for your answer, `string` was a typo. And, yes, I am finding a way to convert fixed-length array to dynamic-sized array. Pushing elements is basically what I did in my contracts... But, it doesn't seem to be good to have...

Comment: I'm nearly certain it's not possible to convert between dynamic and fixed and that's the end of the story. Experience has taught me there's often a clever person who can find a way. This might be one of those times so I left it out of my "answer". What's the concern about push?

Comment: Using some inline assembly, you can turn a fixed-length array into a dynamic one, but it's more readable and not much less efficient to just push each new element on in turn.